# Loop worksheets in excel using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, loops, oledb

I want to loop all the sheets in a excel and need to insert that in a sql server table.

I have done a coding part to insert a single sheet excel into a sql server table.

If the excel contains more worksheets, I want to loop those worksheets and need to insert it in a sql server table.

I have written the following code for looping purpose, but it gives the following error;

> "ComException was caught" "Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due
>   to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

This is the code for looping:

```
string path = @"D:/Projects/sample.xls";
string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Source"].ToString();
string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
var Wbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
foreach (var sheet in Wbook.Worksheets)
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [Name], [City], [Address], [Designation] from [" + sheet + "$]", excelConnection);
                    excelConnection.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader dReader;
                    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
                    //Give your Destination table name
                    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "temp1";
                    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                    excelConnection.Close();
                }
```

But while executing the line

```
var Wbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
```

the above mentioned error arise. Please suggest me.

Comment: Is Excel installed on that machine?

Comment: No. I have not installed MS Office. I have converted the ods format file to excel file.

Comment: That wasn't my question.

Comment: No. I have not installed

Comment: In my office system. we are using only openoffice. No MS Office.

Comment: @thevan Optionally you can make a use of Jet engine that does not require excel to be installed. connectionstring: **Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\";**

Comment: Same error throws when using Jet engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Microsoft Office installed in order to use the interop assemblies, like you do.

You have to either:

- Install Excel;
- or use a third-party component, like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: yes patrick.. i didn't get the desired solution. I tried EPPlus but i got error..

Comment: What I am doing right now is, in a  textbox entering all sheet names with comma, and then placing into a list. Making looping and passing the sheet name individually and storing the values into the db.